# Are these two answers to $\int \sin ^3(x)dx$ equivalent?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

I'm given to integrate $\int \sin ^3(x)dx$. So I used reduction formula which is $$\sin ^{m}(x)dx=-\frac{\cos (x)\sin ^{m-1}(x)}{m}+\frac{m-1}{m}\int \sin ^{-2+m}(x)dx$$ to solve.  I got the answer which is $$\frac{1}{12}(\cos (3x)-9\cos (x))+c$$.

I used another method to solve this. $$\int \sin ^3(x)dx=\int(\sin (x))(\sin ^2(x))dx$$ 
$$=\int (\sin (x))(1-\cos ^2(x))dx$$
$$=\int \sin (x)-\cos ^2(x)\sin (x)dx$$
Let $$u=\cos (x)$$
$$-du=\sin (x)dx$$
$$=-\cos (x)+\int u^2du$$
$$=\frac{1}{3}\cos ^3(x)-\cos (x)+c$$

My question is whether these two answers are equivalent?
How to prove it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: As an aside, see [Wallis' integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis'_integrals).

Comment: A good, quick check is to use a calculator to see what happens when $x=1$. $\frac1{12}(\cos3-9\cos1)\approx-0.48773$, and $\frac13\cos^31-\cos1\approx-0.48773$, and I highly doubt that this is a coincidence. (Of course, this is not a proof.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are equivalent. We have

$$\frac{1}{12}(\cos3x-9\cos x)=\frac{1}{12}(4\cos^3x-3\cos x-9\cos x)=\frac{1}{3}\cos^3x-\cos x$$

The $\cos3x=4\cos^3x-3\cos x$ identity can be found by applying [De Moivre's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula) with $n=3$, equating the real parts of both sides, and finally making the substitution $\sin^2x=1-\cos^2 x$.

Comment: Your explanation is very good. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Mathxx Glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}
&(\frac13\cos^3(x)-\cos(x))'\\&=-\sin(x)\cos^2(x)+\sin(x)\\&=\sin(x)(1-\cos^2(x))\\&=\sin^3(x)\\
&(\frac{1}{12}(\cos(3x)-9\cos(x)))'\\&=\frac{1}{12}(-3\sin(3x)+9\sin(x))\\&=\frac14(3\sin(x)-\sin(3x))\\&=\sin^3(x)
\end{align*}
We have ,$\sin(3x)=3\sin(x)-4\sin^3(x)$

So,the two answers are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

I found an alternative way.

$$\cos 3x=\cos (2x+x)=\cos (2x)\cos (x)-\sin (2x)\sin (x)$$
$$=(2\cos ^2x-1)\cos x-(2\sin x\cos x)\sin x$$ 
$$=2\cos ^3x-\cos x-2\sin ^2x\cos x$$
$$=2\cos ^3x-\cos x-2(1-\cos ^2x)\cos x$$
$$=2\cos ^3x-\cos x-2\cos x+2\cos ^3x$$
$$\cos 3x=4\cos ^3x-3\cos x$$

We have $$\frac{1}{12}(\cos 3x-9\cos x)=\frac{1}{12}(4cos ^3x-3\cos x-9\cos x)$$
$$=\frac{1}{12}(4\cos ^3x-12\cos x)=\frac{1}{3}\cos ^3x-\cos x$$